# How to create a specific AutoHotKey clicker Script

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to learn how to make auto clickers with AutoHotKey. I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want though. I want it to hold the left mouse button for 5 seconds, release for 5 seconds, and repeat. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not too hard if you study the help materials.  Try the following and note, you can adjust the wait times or do other things in between the two times you press the mouse down:

```
click Down
sleep, 5000
click up

sleep, 500

click Down
sleep, 5000
click up

return
```

And, if you need multiple repeats, you can put it in a loop:

```
loop, 5
{
click Down
sleep, 5000
click up
sleep, 500
}

return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm

**Click** [v1.0.43+]

Clicks a mouse button at the specified coordinates. It can also hold down a mouse button, turn the mouse wheel, or move the mouse.

Here are examples of common usages (all commas are optional):

Click (by itself) Clicks the left mouse button once at the mouse cursor's current position.

Click 44, 55 Clicks the left mouse button once at coordinates 44, 55 (based on CoordMode).

Click right 44, 55 Same as above but clicks the right mouse button.

Click 2 Clicks the left mouse button twice at the cursor's current position (i.e. double-click).

***Click down*** Presses the left mouse button down and holds it.

***Click up*** right Releases the right mouse button.

Click %x% %y% Since click does not support expressions, variables should be enclosed in percent signs.

Zero or more of the following items can follow the word Click. Separate each item from the next with at least one space, tab, and/or comma. The items can appear in any order except ClickCount, which must occur somewhere to the right of the coordinates (if coordinates are present).

X, Y: The x/y coordinates to which the mouse cursor is moved prior to clicking. Coordinates are relative to the active window unless CoordMode was used to change that. If omitted, the cursor's current position is used.

Button Name: Left (default), Right, Middle (or just the first letter of each of these); or the fourth or fifth mouse button (X1 or X2). NOTE: Unlike MouseClick, the left and right buttons behave consistently across all systems, even if the user has swapped the buttons via the system's control panel.

Mouse Wheel: Specify WheelUp or WU to turn the wheel upward (away from you); specify WheelDown or WD to turn the wheel downward (toward you). In v1.0.48+, WheelLeft (or WL) or WheelRight (or WR) may also be specified (but they have no effect on older operating systems older than Windows Vista). For ClickCount (below), specify the number of notches to turn the wheel. However, some applications do not obey a ClickCount higher than 1 for the mouse wheel. For them, use a Loop such as the following:
Loop 5
    Click WheelUp

ClickCount: The number of times to click the mouse (examples: Click 2, Click 100, 200, 2). If omitted, the button is clicked once. If coordinates are specified, ClickCount must appear after them. Specify zero (0) to move the mouse without clicking (for example: Click 100, 200, 0).

**Down or Up:** These words are normally omitted, in which case each click consists of a down-event followed by an up-event. Otherwise, specify Down (or the letter D) to press the mouse button down without releasing it. Later, use the word Up (or the letter U) to release the mouse button.

Relative: The word Rel or Relative treats the specified X and Y coordinates as offsets from the current mouse position. In other words, the cursor will be moved from its current position by X pixels to the right (left if negative) and Y pixels down (up if negative).